# Converting 1D vector into 2D in C++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a 1D vector(Vp_cpp) and I want to convert to 2D vector(declared as Vp_2D). However, my implementation is somewhat not correct because it couldn't be able to reach the line "Out from inner loop".

```
std::vector<double> Vp_cpp;
std::vector<std::vector<double> > Vp_2D;

Vp_2D.resize(N_cpp);
for (int i = 0; i < N_cpp; ++i)
    Vp_2D[i].resize(N_cpp);
for (int j = 0; j < N_cpp; j++)
    for (int k = 0; k < N_cpp; k++)
{
    cout << "Beginning inner loop" << endl;
    Vp_2D[i_cpp][i_cpp2] = Vp_cpp[i_cpp2]; 
    cout << "Out from inner loop" << endl;
}
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: error message? exception? what happends when you run this? do you have more detail regarding "Couldn't be able to reach the line "..""

Comment: what is `i_cpp` and `i_cpp2`? There' not shown anywhere other than inside your inner loop - no declaration/definition or assignments.

Comment: I think `i_cpp` and `i_cpp2` should be `j` and `k`.

Comment: Your iteration variables are j and k and in the assignment you are using i_cpp and i_cpp2. What are the values of i_cpp and i_cpp2?

Comment: What are `N_cpp`, `i_cpp` and `i_cpp2`?

Comment: What above comments say between the lines: post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line seems wrong to me:

```
Vp_2D[i_cpp][i_cpp2] = Vp_cpp[i_cpp2];
```

I would write:

```
Vp_2D[j][k] = Vp_cpp[i++];
```

where `i` is used to iterate over `Vp_cpp`. It should be initialized to 0 before the `for (int j, ...` loop.

Answer (score 2):

change the line

```
Vp_2D[i_cpp][i_cpp2] = Vp_cpp[i_cpp2];
```

to

```
Vp_2D[j][k] = Vp_cpp[(j * N_cpp) + k];
```

Otherwise you'll just re-assign one value lots of times.

Answer (score 1):

`Vp_2D[i_cpp][i_cpp2] = Vp_cpp[i_cpp2];` everytime your loop passes through this instruction it will keep resetting the value at `Vp_2D[i_cpp][i_cpp2]` (since there is no visible assignments on `i_cpp` and `i_cpp2` inside the loop.)

You should change it to be `Vp_2D[j][k]`.

Comment: "I think" is never an acceptable answer according to me. "I think" should be added as comments (or be rewritten).

Comment: @Default:- How will you answer this question? "Whats wrong with this code `char* x=malloc(10)`". In comment?? **add (char*) before malloc** !!! ?????

Comment: not sure what you are asking about or why you're using multiple question marks. Was my comment unclear? I was remarking on the following line: *I think it should be...*, which according to me **should** be "It should be...". If you don't know the answer (which is implied by "I think") I don't believe that it should be put as an answer. Do you see what I am getting at? And the answer to your question is correct. note that you didn't write "**I think** you should add (char*) before malloc"

Comment: :) Its just irony... such silly questions dont need comments.you can see how simple was the answer that as per SO, it will go for comment.

Comment: I took the liberty to rewrite your answer. I hope that makes it more clear as what my point was. Now, the answer doesn't state "I think" anymore.